# Does every exception have an required try-catch?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

A simple question and I can't find the answer for it.
Is it required to every exception in Java to use a try-catch? Or is it only for the FileNotFoundException?

A lot of exceptions (IndexOutOfBoundException, ArithmeticException, IlligalArgumentException, NullPointerException) are saying that they didn't need an Exception, but FileNotFoundException does)... and I can't find the answer which do and which doesn't need try-catch.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more.

Comment: Read it here [Exception oracle doc] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Comment: No. Look up checked vs. unchecked exceptions.

Comment: I add some more info in the post.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's not absolutely required to have a `try/catch` block for your exceptions. Instead, you can `throw` them to someone who is able to handle the exception properly.

There are 2 kinds of exceptions: Checked and Unchecked. A Checked exception **can be considered** one that is found by the compiler, and the compiler knows that it has a chance to occur, so you need to `catch` or `throw` it. For example, opening a file. It has a chance to fail, and the compiler knows this, so you're forced to `catch` or `throw` the possible `IOException`.

An Unchecked exception **can be considered** one that has a chance of occurring, but based on your code, the compiler doesn't know. In other words, it's a *programming error*. For example, if you're taking user input and expect a number, and the user enters something you didn't expect, such as a string, your program would throw a `NumberFormatException`. You can predict these scenarios and put `try/catch` to try and avoid them before they occur. Very rarely seen is a person adding a `throws NullPointerException` or `throws NumberFormatException` (or throwing any other Unchecked exception, for that matter). It's allowed, but explicitly creating that exception is weird and most people would say that it's bad coding style.

Note that all Checked suggestions **must** be caught or thrown to something that can handle it; if you don't do it, your program won't compile. If you throw it to something that can't handle it, then your program will likely crash if it occurs.

Also note that an unchecked Exception (eg: one that occurs during runtime, usually via bad user input or whatnot) will also usually crash your program. Thus, it's usually a good idea to use `try/catch` when something can potentially go wrong, but **you don't have to**.

Also interesting to note is that while Checked exceptions are subclasses of Exception and Unchecked exceptions are subclasses of RuntimeException, RuntimeException itself is a subclass of Exception. That means that if you really wanted to, a single `try {} catch (Exception e) {}` will catch every single exception your program could possibly throw. Granted, this is considered a horrible way to deal with exceptions, and you should catch each one separately so that you can handle them separately. Please try not to use it.

Comment: Oracle's documentation for this concept: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 4):

No, not every exception requires a try-catch.  Every checked exception requires a try catch.  For example, a NullPointerException is an unchecked exception, so it does not require a try-catch, whereas a FileNotFoundException is checked, so it does require one.  You can also add "throws" to the method signature and thus avoid needing a try-catch.

Comment: Unexpected exceptions is bad terminology to describe non-RuntimeException

Comment: You're right.  The correct terminology is "checked" and "unchecked."  I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Read:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Basically checked Exceptions need to be handled or thrown
Unchecked Exceptions and Errors may be handled or thrown (although handling Error is in general considered bad practise).

Checked exception is everything that inherits from java.lang.Exception

Unchecked exception is everything that inherits from java.lang.RuntimeException

Error is everything that inherits from java.lang.Error

Answer (score 1):

Only Checked exception explicit need to catch it, for other all kind of exception you can use "throws" to the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if you don't want to handle it in your method you can pass the exception to the caller of the method with the `throws` keyword. Example:

```
void execption() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}

void caller() {
    try {
        execption();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm a bit rusty on my java, like josh said you can have unchecked exceptions that don't need a try/catch like `NullPointerException`, but you can add one if you think an unchecked exception may be thrown. Example:

```
Object obj = null;

obj.hashCode();// if you think a NPE will be thrown you can use a try/catch here
```

Answer (score 0):

When a method that you call explicitly throws an exception then you have to use `try....catch` loop. But in case of the list you have given are all runtime exceptions. They get thrown when sometimes a program has inputs that were not expected or the program was put to some use that it was not intended for. These would not require a `try....catch` loop.