# What's the point of try/catch blocks to catch Exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

Why do we need try/catch blocks to catch any Exceptions that may arise in our code? Once we run the program and lets assume we have a RuntimeException, won't the program just automatically abort and give us the error anyways? Why do we need try/catch blocks to do this for us then?

Comment: Precisely to *avoid* aborting the program. But you generally don't catch "any exception that may arise". You catch exception that you can deal with in a meaningful manner. Let's say you ask the user to enter a date, and he/she enters garbage. You don't want to crash the program. You want to catch the parse excepion and ask the user to fix the input and enter a valid date again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does every exception have an required try-catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851253/does-every-exception-have-an-required-try-catch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the scenarios when working with a live website or application. You wouldn't want the user to see a blank screen or a screen full of error trace code. In such scenarios, potential areas of exception can be handled to show a message to the user that makes sense "sorry, you are exceeding more than 10 items in your cart  etc ", "you do not have sufficient amount in your account", "username cannot have symbols ", "out service us un-operational right now please come back later".

Try catch is used to handle the such error conditions gracefully. You can enclose a code set into try and its catch would be responsible to handle it. Handling may depend on your use case but your java program wont terminate.

Abrupt termination of program doesn't let you know the actual reason of failure.

Answer (score 7):

It's just good practice. If the user is given with something like "IndexOutOfrangeexception" what is he going to do with it? Just assume everything is OK and he should start over? What in case of doing some work with the software - is the work lost? What happened?

Put yourself in such stuation: you downloaded some software, you start using it as normal, and you are happy with it. But one day you run program and it gives you error and program dies - do you know what happened? No. Do you know what went wrong? No. Do you know how to prevent it and start using software so the error doesn't occur again? No.

YOU ARE THE DEVELOPER, you know what happens inside. So for example, you are trying to save data in database, but somehow connection got lost and you will likely get an exception - in catch block you can catch this exception and give the user MEANINGFUL information, e.g. "The connection with database is lost. Check the network. Your data is not saved and you should do the work again." - isn't that better than just some "SQL exception" alongside with the stacktrace?

Additionally, catch/finally blocks are here to clean-up potential mess, for example you are writing some content to a file, but it only makes sense, when you can write all data, not just the part of it. So in catch block you could erase incomplete data, so the file is not corrupted for example.

Also, when working with unanaged resources, you should use finally block to clean them up (for example DB/netowrk connections).

Answer (score 1):

Because if you don't catch an exception the entire method execution will simply stop, including the execution of any calling methods. So if a method A needs something of method B and calls it, and method B throws an exception, then that exception will cause method A to stop execution. If method A was being called by another method that method will stop execution too if it doesn't catch the exception from method B. So an exception will work its way up the method calling chain until it is catched by a method or gets to the most upper/outer method.

Also, any exception that is not inheriting from the `RuntimeException` class or is not an instance of the `RuntimeException` class itself must either be catched or else your code will not compile. If you really don't want to handle this kind of exception then you can also let the calling method receive the exception by adding `throws Exception` to your method signature. A runtimeexception extending class is called an `unchecked` exception, you don't have to include that in the method or in the method signature. Anything extending Exception but not RuntimeException is called a `checked` exception and should either be catched or put in the method signature by using `throws` keyword.

EDIT: Here you can find a good explanation too [Does every exception have an required try-catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851253/does-every-exception-have-an-required-try-catch)

Comment: Also, RuntimeException extends Exception. So your explanation on what a checked exception is is not accurate.

Comment: @JBNizet im aware of that but it is not mandatory to propagate or catch a runtime exception or an exception that extends that class

Comment: RIght. That doesn't make this statement true= "Anything extending Exception is called a checked exception".

Answer (score 0):

Other than examples users given, also, on Android for hardware specific operations, camera for instance, can throw RuntimeExceptions even you do everything right, it does it a lot with camera based on devices. I set ISO for instance camera and it's not a crucial for my app to work but i don't want my app to crash so i throw an exception and show a warning to user so app continue to work.