# Java - Avoid pattern duplication

Tags: java, design-patterns

**Java**
In my server code, for each method I will have to do the following

```
    @Path("...")
    public Response function(...) {
        try {
            result = do some work to get result
            log the result
            return result
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log error
            return error
        }
    }
```

I will have to duplicate this pattern everywhere and only changing the `do some work to get result` part for new endpoint.

Is there a way that I can do to reduce this is duplication?

P.S. `do some work to get result` can be very something like getting a Json file, or accessing multiple database and calculate the result, and need to be in try-catch block.

Comment: Map your exceptions to unchecked exceptions then there would be no need for try catches!  Not a fan of this. but didn't Spring Framework Or Hibernate have some way of doing something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851253/does-every-exception-have-an-required-try-catch https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/enterprise-architecture/effective-exceptions-part2.html

Comment: @JGFMK but that does not allow you to return specific (i.e. based on the request) error responses in case of an exception

Comment: Is the exception handling equal or is it different in each function?

Comment: exception handling will be the same for all the functions

Comment: @JGFMK thank you, it's look like something I should have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that looks like this:

```
  public static <T> T doTheThing(Supplier<T> supp, Supplier<T> errorSupp) {
    try {
      T result = supp.get();
      //log the result
      return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //log error
      return errorSupp.get();
    }
  }
```

Then you can pass suppliers for a) the actual work and b) the potential error to this function.